# Dividing a list of vertices between left and right sides

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I am trying to divide a spheres selected vertices between left and right 
(by measuring the the vertices `x` value via `pointPosition`). If I have 2 vertices on the left and one on the right selected however,
it returns that I have 3 on the left, instead of 2 on the left 
and one on the right.

How should I restructure the loop so it correctly creates an exclusively left or right list?

```
import maya.cmds as mc

iObj = mc.ls( sl = True, flatten = True )
selSize = len( iObj )

for numVert in range ( 0, selSize ):

    posSel = mc.ls( sl = True, flatten = True )
    posSelPos = mc.pointPosition( posSel[ numVert ], world = True )

    if posSelPos[ 0 ] > 0:

        leftVerts.append( posSel )
        leftSideSize = len( leftVerts[ 0 ] )
        print "Lside has " + "%s" % ( leftSideSize )
        print leftSideSize           
        print leftVerts[ 0 ]

    elif posSelPos[ 0 ] < 0:

        rightVerts.append( posSel )
        rightSideSize = len( rightVerts[ 0 ] )
        print "Rside has " + "%s" % ( rightSideSize )           
        print rightSideSize
        print rightVerts[ 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a misleading answer it may be because you've got verts on the 0 coordinate.  In your test you're going to get things larger than or less than zero, but nothing that sits at exactly zero.

Collecting the values is pretty simple, you can do it a bit more elegantly with [python list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# make a list of verts, using filterexpand so you don't get 
# ranges like pCube1.vtx[1:3]

selected = cmds.filterExpand(cmds.ls(sl=True), sm=31)   

items_by_position = [ (vtx, cmds.pointPosition(vtx)) for vtx in selected] 
# this gives you a list of [(vertex, position), (vertex, position)] pairs 

left = [item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] > 0]
right = [item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] < 0]
middle = [item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] == 0]

print "left\n", left
print "right\n", right
print "middle\n", middle
```

You might find it handy to turn the left, right and middle lists into dictionaries:

```
selected = cmds.filterExpand(cmds.ls(sl=True), sm=31)       
items_by_position = [ (vtx, cmds.pointPosition(vtx)) for vtx in selected]
left = dict([item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] > 0])
right = dict([item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] < 0])
middle = dict([item for item in items_by_position if item[1][0] == 0])
```

So you could grab the position of the vertex out of the list.  If you flip

```
(vtx, cmds.pointPosition(vtx))
```

into

```
(cmds.pointPosition(vtx), vtx)
```

and check item[0] instead of item[1](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), your dictionaries will be keyed by position